# Summarize all group values and a conditional subset in the same call

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

I'll illustrate my question with an example.

Sample data:

```
 df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5), A = c("foo", "bar", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"), B =     c(1, 5, 7, 23, 54, 202))

df
  ID   A   B
1  1 foo   1
2  1 bar   5
3  2 foo   7
4  2 foo  23
5  3 bar  54
6  5 bar 202
```

What I want to do is to summarize, by ID, the sum of B and the sum of B when A is "foo". I can do this in a couple steps like:

```
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(sumB = sum(B))

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(A == "foo") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(sumBfoo = sum(B))

left_join(df1, df2)

  ID sumB sumBfoo
1  1    6       1
2  2   30      30
3  3   54      NA
4  5  202      NA
```

However, I'm looking for a more elegant/faster way, as I'm dealing with 10gb+ of out-of-memory data in sqlite.

```
require(sqldf)
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
df_sqlite <- copy_to(my_db, df)
```

I thought of using `mutate` to define a new `Bfoo` column:

```
df_sqlite %>%
  mutate(Bfoo = ifelse(A=="foo", B, 0))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on the database end of things.

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such function: IFELSE)
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are trying to mix character and numeric in Bfoo which is not possible

Comment: @beginneR it's all numeric and the code runs fine locally...

Comment: What versions of R and dplry are you using? Your code ran fine for me locally as well (after I changed %>% to %.%).

Comment: @MrFlick yeah it's supposed to run "locally" (by that I meant on a data.frame and not in the sqlite database). I'm trying to figure out how to best run it in sqlite, which doesn't recognize "ifelse"

Comment: @pearpies I don't understand. Is this running in R? or is this running in sqllite? How is it getting to the database?

Comment: sorry my OP is a bit confusing. will edit

Comment: Try using `if(A=="foo") B else 0` - dplyr will try to convert that to a SQL case statement, which might work for you.

Comment: In case anyone is looking to summarize based on mathematical conditions (instead of matching strings): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199273/summarize-with-mathematical-conditions-in-dplyr/59199366#59199366

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Writing up @hadley's comment as an answer

```
df_sqlite %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Bfoo = if(A=="foo") B else 0) %>%
  summarize(sumB = sum(B),
            sumBfoo = sum(Bfoo)) %>%
  collect
```

Comment: what is the function of `dplyr::collect` here?

Comment: `collect` forces the evaluation of the verbs prior to it

Answer (score 137):

You can do both sums in a single `dplyr` statement:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(sumB = sum(B),
            sumBfoo = sum(B[A=="foo"]))
```

And here is a `data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)

dt = setDT(df) 

dt1 = dt[ , .(sumB = sum(B),
              sumBfoo = sum(B[A=="foo"])), 
          by = ID]

dt1
```

> ```
>    ID sumB sumBfoo
> 1:  1    6       1
> 2:  2   30      30
> 3:  3   54       0
> 4:  5  202       0
> ```

Comment: this would work if I could fit everything into memory. i'll definitely keep it in mind. problem is sql doesn't recognize ``[``. sorry i wasn't clear in the question!

Comment: The dplyr database vignette might be helpful for future reference (in case you haven't already seen it): http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html

Comment: How could I miss that in the documentation?! Imho one of dplyr's most useful functionalities for dealing with data, especially when working with tidy data.

Comment: great answer! Have not come across this kind  of subsetting before : `df %>% summarize(function(colname[conditional_colname]))`

Comment: Wow, never knew u could subset like that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @eipi10 I'm aware of how old this answer is, but do you happen to know the `data.table` alternative for the conditional `A == "foo"` that you used for `sumBfoo`?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to do counting instead of summarizing, then the answer is somewhat different. The change in code is small, especially in the conditional counting part.

```
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(countB = n(),
              countBfoo = sum(A=="foo"))

df1
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

  ID countB countBfoo
1  1      2         1
2  2      2         2
3  3      1         0
4  5      1         0
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to count the rows, instead of summing them, can you pass a variable to the function:

```
    df1 <- df %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarize(RowCountB = n(),
          RowCountBfoo = n(A=="foo"))
```

I get an error both with `n()` and `nrow()`.

Comment: Is this an answer or another question?