# ifelse & grepl commands when using dplyr for SQL in-db operations

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, dplyr

In dplyr running on R data frames, it is easy to run

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(income_topcoded = ifelse(income > topcode, income, topcode)
```

I'm now working with a large SQL database, using dplyr to send commands to the SQL server. When I run the same command, I get back

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  
function ifelse  (boolean, numeric, numeric) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

How would you suggest implementing `ifelse()` statements? I'd be fine with something in PivotalR (which seems to support `ifelse()`, but I don't know how to integrate it with dplyr and couldn't find any examples on SO), some piece of SQL syntax which I can use in-line here, or some feature of dplyr which I was unaware of.

(I have the same problem that I'd like to use `grepl()` as an in-db operation, but I don't know how to do so.)

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to make it a specific, programming question? As it stands right now it has a good  chance of being closed as off-topic (looking for a tool, tutorial...).

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the tip! Just rewrote it. If I have questions of the form "looking for a tool" in the future, where would you suggest I post them?

Comment: I really wouldn't know. Perhaps a mailing list that deals in a similar topic? I usually just do an internet search or ask in the R chat room here on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @hadley's reply on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr), you can use an SQL-style `if()` statement inside `mutate()` on dplyr's in-db dataframes:

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate( income_topcoded = if (income > topcode) income else topcode)
```

As far as using `grepl()` goes...well, you can't. But you can use the SQL `like` operator:

```
df  <- df %>%
    filter( topcode %like% "ABC%" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  The best I could do was to use an in-db operation as you suggest:

```
topcode <- 10000
queryString <- sprintf("UPDATE db.table SET income_topcoded = %s WHERE income_topcoded > %s",topcode,topcode)
dbGetQuery(con, queryString)
```

In my case, I was using MySQL with `dplyr`, but it wasn't able to translate my `ifelse()` into valid SQL.

Comment: this is pretty clean and i will use it going forward. thanks! (not giving it a check since I still hope that dplyr's creators will build this functionality in the future)