# Summarize with conditions and implicit column names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to perform a conditional summation using `R` and `dplyr` using implicit column names.  So starting with

```
> df <- data.frame(colA=c(1,2,1,1),
+                  colB=c(0,0,3,1),
+                  colC=c(0,1,2,3),
+                  colD=c(2,2,2,2))
> df
  colA colB colC colD
1    1    0    0    2
2    2    0    1    2
3    1    3    2    2
4    1    1    3    2
```

I am trying to apply the psuedocode:

```
foreach column c
    if(row.val > 1)
        calc += (row.val - 1)
```

I can accomplish this in a fairly straightforward manner using some simple  base `R` subsetting:

```
> df.ans <- data.frame(calcA = sum(df$colA[df$colA > 1] - 1),
+                      calcB = sum(df$colB[df$colB > 1] - 1),
+                      calcC = sum(df$colC[df$colC > 1] - 1),
+                      calcD = sum(df$colD[df$colD > 1] - 1))
> df.ans
  calcA calcB calcC calcD
1     1     2     3     4
```

However I would like a solution that does not have to explicitly state the column names (`colA`, `colB`, etc.) because there are many and they may change in the future.  If I were doing a simple `sum` the calculation would be possible with `dplyr` and:

```
df %>% 
summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

Things I have tried:

- The `filter_at` components of `dplyr` but found that insufficient for this purpose because they take entire rows, whereas I am filtering rows per column independently.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr) answer but found it insufficient because it uses explicit column names.
- Conditionals inside a custom `summarise` function.  This is probably the closest I have gotten but the evaluations always resolve to booleans which throw off the summation.  For example `summarise_all(funs(sum(. > 1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate the hard coding example to `summarize_all` pretty easily as, i.e, replace `df$col..` with `.`:

```
df %>% summarise_all(~ sum(.[. > 1] - 1))

#  colA colB colC colD
#1    1    2    3    4
```

Or with the `funs` syntax:

```
df %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(.[. > 1] - 1)))

#  colA colB colC colD
#1    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on the purpose/need for the `~`.  I tried this exact solution (minus the `~`) and spend a nontrivial amount of time researching the error "Can't create call to non-callable object" to no avail.  The `summarize_all` documentation also has no examples where the `~` is used.

Comment: `~` is the purrr/tidyverse syntax for creating a function, which serves the same purpose as `funs`, i.e. `df %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(.[. > 1] - 1)))` . Both syntax should work in `0.7.4` (my current dplyr version), if you get an error, you can either switch to the `funs` syntax or upgrade `dplyr` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sapply` from base R:

```
sapply(df,function(x)sum(x[x>1]-1))
colA colB colC colD 
   1    2    3    4
```