# Using dplyr summarise with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am currently trying to apply the summarise function in order to isolate the relevant observations from a large data set. A simple reproducible example is given here:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), as.logical(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)),
                 as.numeric(c(0,5,0,0,0,0,7,0,7)))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Status", "Price")

  ID Status Price
1  1   TRUE     0
2  1  FALSE     5
3  1   TRUE     0
4  2   TRUE     0
5  2   TRUE     0
6  2   TRUE     0
7  3  FALSE     7
8  3   TRUE     0
9  3  FALSE     7
```

I would like to sort the table by observation and get the status TRUE only if all three observations are TRUE (figured out) and then want to get the price corresponding to the status (i.e. 5 for observation 1 as FALSE, 0 for observation 2 as TRUE and 7 for observation 3 as FALSE).

From [Summarize with conditions in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr) I have figured out that I can - just as usually - specify the conditions in square brackets. My code so far thus looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Status = all(Status), Test = ifelse(all(Status) == TRUE,
 first(Price[Status == TRUE]), first(Price[Status == FALSE]))) 

# This is what I get: 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID Status  Test
  <dbl> <lgl>  <dbl>
1    1. FALSE     0.
2    2. TRUE      0.
3    3. FALSE     7.
```

But as you can see, for ID = 1 it gives an incorrect price. I have been trying this forever, so I would appreciate any hint as to where I have been going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could keep the `all(Status)` as second argument in `summarise` (or change the column name) and also, it can be done with `if/else` as the logic seems to return a single TRUE/FALSE based on whether `all` of the 'Status' is TRUE or not

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise( Test = if(all(Status)) first(Price[Status]) else 
                   first(Price[!Status]), Status = all(Status))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     ID  Test Status
#   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
#1     1     5 FALSE 
#2     2     0 TRUE  
#3     3     7 FALSE
```

NOTE: It is better not to use `ifelse` with unequal lengths for its arguments

Answer (score 1):

Could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(status = Status) %>%
  summarise(
    Status = all(Status),
    Test = ifelse(Status == TRUE,
                  first(Price),
                  first(Price[status == FALSE]))
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID Status  Test
  <dbl> <lgl>  <dbl>
1     1 FALSE      5
2     2 TRUE       0
3     3 FALSE      7
```

The issue is that you want to use `Status` for `Test` column while you've already modified it so that it doesn't contain original values anymore.

Make a copy before (I've saved it in `status`), execute `ifelse` on it and it'll run fine.