# I want to calculate mean value from specific group and put the value as variable on the other groups

Tags: r, calculation

Hope anyone can help me to solve this question.

I have following this data.

```
Age_group, Mode, speed
1, car, 20
2, car,30
3, car,40
4, car,50
1, Bike, 20
2, Bike,30
2, Bike,40
3, Bike, 40
3, Bike,50
4, Bike,50
```

I would like to get this result, where the Bike_speed of mode car, based on the mean value of mode Bike.

```
Age_group, Mode, Speed, Bike_speed
1, car, 20,2
2, car,30,3.5
3, car,40,4.5
4, car,50,5
1, Bike, 2,2
2, Bike,3,3.5
2, Bike,4,3.5
3, Bike,4, 4.5
3, Bike,5,4.5
4, Bike,5,4.5
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `tidyverse` package

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`

```
library(tidyverse)
# compute mean speed for bike mode by age group
bike_mean_df <- df %>% filter(Mode=="Bike") %>%
     group_by(Age_group) %>%
     summarise(Bike_speed=mean(speed))
# join to original dataframe
df %>% left_join(bike_mean_df)
```