# Additional columns for a summarised DataFrame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add columns to a summarized data frame that counts a particular factor.

```
bookplace <- data.frame(type = c("reading", "reading", "reading", "reading", "lending", "lending"), 
                        sex = c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female"), 
                        usage = c(103, 102, 23, 14, 16, 8), 
                        date = c("1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The result should be (considering male and female as the added columns):

```
year  type    users  male  female
2018  lending    24    16       8
2018  reading   242   126     116
```

I tried using mutate to add the column and then summarize with the following code:

```
bookplace %>% 
  mutate(males=count(sex=="male"),
         females=count(sex=="female")) %>%
  group_by(year=format(date,"%Y"), type) %>% 
  summarize(users=sum(usage))
```

But I have the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
>     no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "logical"

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please create your example correctly.  Not clear about the expected output.  What are 'users' based on the input example

Comment: Hello akrun, I have edited the example, 'users' is the sum of 'usage'.

Comment: okay, then what is `usage`?

Comment: Hello, I added what 'usage' is, is defined as the name of the third column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidyverse solution. Assuming that dates are `%m/%d/%y`. If not, change the format string accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bookplace %>% 
  mutate(year = format(as.Date("1/1/18", "%m/%d/%y"), "%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(year, sex, type) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(usage)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(sex, Total) %>% 
  mutate(users = female + male)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  year  type    female  male users
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018  lending      8    16    24
2 2018  reading    116   126   242
```

Comment: Is the solution I needed. Thank you very much @neilfws

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer using dplyr

```
bookplace <- data.frame(c("reading", "reading", "reading", 
                          "reading", "lending", "lending"), 
                        c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female"), 
                        c(103, 102, 23, 14, 16, 8), 
                        c("1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18","1/1/18"))
colnames(bookplace) <- c("type","Gender","Usage","Year")
bookplace$Year <- as.Date(bookplace$Year, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
check <- bookplace%>%group_by(Year,type)%>%summarise(Users = sum(Usage),male = sum(Usage[ Gender =="male"]),
                                                     female = sum(Usage[Gender == "female"]))
```

i got the idea from this question 
[Summarize with conditions in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr)

Comment: Hello @Omar Abd El-Naser your solution worked good too. Thank you.