# Identify duplicates based on duplicated data and some additional conditions, using `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I was checking out this answer ([Summarize all group values and a conditional subset in the same call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-all-group-values-and-a-conditional-subset-in-the-same-call)) as it gives me the right idea (setting a `dupe` column), but I need some more help.

So my data is structured something like this (medical data so keeping it as anonymised as possible):

| index | name | category | date | checkup_complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | cat1 | date1 | Y |
| 2 | name1 | cat1 | date1 | N |
| 3 | name1 | cat2 | date1 | Y |
| 4 | name1 | cat1 | date1 | Y |
| 5 | name1 | cat1 | date2 | N |
| 6 | name2 | cat1 | date1 | Y |
| 7 | name3 | cat1 | date2 | Y |
| 8 | name2 | cat2 | date1 | Y |
| 9 | name3 | cat1 | date2 | N |
| 10 | name2 | cat2 | date1 | Y |
| 11 | name1 | cat1 | date1 | N |

Data is considered a duplicate if it fits the following criteria:

For a given `category`, if there are multiple `name`s with the same name, on the same `date` with `checkup_complete` == *"Y"*. The ones matching this criteria will get collapsed to a single record.

So based on this, the duplicates are indices: 1 and 4; 8 and 10. Indices 2 and 11 are **not** duplicates.

The actual table is 10s of 000s of rows, so is there a way I can use **dplyr** (as I'm using it as part of the overall data-frame workflow) to mark these are duplicates or not?

Based on the link I provided above I sense that I would use **group_by** on `category`, `name`, `date`, and **mutate** a `dupe` column. Question is, without creating another column (`cond_dupe`) to then filter based on `checkup_complete` AND `dupe`, is there a way of doing it in one go?

Comment: I think you want `dplyr::distinct`

Comment: @TTS: Can I use `dplyr::distinct` across `name`, `category` and `date`, whilst setting a specific condition for `checkup_complete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df %>% group_by(category, name, date, checkup_complete) %>% filter(if(all(checkup_complete == 'Y')) row_number() == n() else TRUE)
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   category, name, date, checkup_complete [8]
  index name  category date  checkup_complete
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>           
1     2 name1 cat1     date1 N               
2     3 name1 cat2     date1 Y               
3     4 name1 cat1     date1 Y               
4     5 name1 cat1     date2 N               
5     6 name2 cat1     date1 Y               
6     7 name3 cat1     date2 Y               
7     9 name3 cat1     date2 N               
8    10 name2 cat2     date1 Y               
9    11 name1 cat1     date1 N
```

Comment: Ah whoops, let me correct that: indices 8 and 10 should have had the same date, sorry.

Comment: @azymandius, the code should work, can you please try and let me know

Comment: What is the purpose of `filter(row_number() == n())`?

Comment: @azymandius, it selects the last row in the group, if you give `1` inplace of `n()` it will select first row.

Comment: @azymandius, does my code answer your question?

Comment: Clever, I like it. I realise I forgot another variation in my data to take into account the actual condition I'm having trouble with. Have updated the table with an 11th index. I don't want indices 2 and 11 to be collapsed to 1 item since as long as `checkup_complete` == *"N"*, they don't count as duplicates even if they have the same `name`, `category` and `date`.

Comment: @azymandius, have updated my answer, please check if that works

Comment: Thanks heaps, it worked perfectly. I was just testing it with a manual version (with a number of transformations with `distinct`) and I get the same results so this is much easier to maintain. Could you explain what `filter(if(all(checkup_complete == 'Y')) row_number() == n() else TRUE)` does? I understand that it checks for all rows where `checkup_complete` == *'Y'*. What does `else TRUE` achieve?

Comment: @azymandius,  `else TRUE` is catch all, i.e. all other cases are filtered in.