# Summarise based on condition with different length (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, summarize

having a tibbl df:

```
A B C
1 0 -1
2 1 2
-3 -2 1
```

I need to filter all columns based on a condition and summarize them to a new variable (I know the legth is different then, but is there an else option for "NA"?

I know it works when I sum them or min/max etc.
[Summarize all group values and a conditional subset in the same call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-all-group-values-and-a-conditional-subset-in-the-same-call/55781564#55781564)

```
df %>% summarise(A_to_B = (A[A < 0]),
B_to_A = (A[A > 0]),
B_to_C = (B[B < 0]),
C_to_B = (B[B > 0]),
C_to_B = (C[C < 0]),
B_to_C = (C[C > 0]))
```

Hope it is clear what I mean, I want to sort a variable to a new one, if it doesn't fit to the condition it should be NA to have the same length for a resulting tibble/df.

Edit: Expected output:

```
A_to_B B_to_A B_to_C  ....
NA      1      NA
NA      2      NA
-3      NA     -2
```

It is litterally a split of each variable (column) based on a condition.
Thanks!

Comment: @zx8754 added the output for the first three conditions, it's more or less a split of the variables based on condition. If necessary,  could also include the zero in one of the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps using `replace`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0, use summarize below

df %>% 
  reframe(across(A:C, ~ replace(.x, !(.x < 0), NA), .names="{.col}_lt_0"), 
          across(A:C, ~ replace(.x, !(.x > 0), NA), .names="{.col}_gt_0")) 
  A_lt_0 B_lt_0 C_lt_0 A_gt_0 B_gt_0 C_gt_0
1     NA     NA     -1      1     NA     NA
2     NA     NA     NA      2      1      2
3     -3     -2     NA     NA     NA      1
```

Comment: Interesting solution, seems to be a feature of dplyr 1.1.0 that is new to me: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/reframe.html;  still run 1.0.10 in R4.2.2

Comment: Yes, you can use `summarize` to get the same results < 1.1.0